# sudo dpkg-reconfigure foo

Tags: apt, dpkg, configuration

Many times I see `sudo dpkg-reconfigure foo`. What is that? Seems to be configuration? But what is the relation between that and .conf file? Is there any file which stores this configuration?

If you need example:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

I need some more description what I know is just it is for package configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packages (like `postfix`) may install or generate configuration files (files that usually go in the `/etc` folder). During this process, there may be options that can be changed by the user. On installation, you are usually asked to set these options. In the case of `postfix`, it involves what type of server you're running, the hostname, and allowed IP addresses (among other things).

If you wanted to change those options afterwards, though, you can use `dpkg-reconfigure` which only goes through the configuration files phase of the package, where you can change those options.

Note that not all packages have user-configurable options, so even if a package installs a configuration file in `/etc`, `dpkg-reconfigure` might not do anything.

Comment: To find out which packages on the system _are_ `dpkg-reconfigure`-able, you can run `sudo debconf-show --listowners`